# Как удалить несколько элементов списка <li> с конца?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть некий список:

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Он генерируется с помощью запроса за счет массива/объекта:

```
results = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

но приходит другой  запрос для этого же списка с меньшим массивом:

```
results = [1,2,3]
```

необходимо удалить определеное количество элементов (разницу) `<li>` этого же списка .

Я попытался что-то придумать, но не совсем выходит. Подскажите, пожалуйста

Мой JS:

```js
liColl = document.querySelectorAll('li')
if (results.length < liColl.length) {
  let diff = liColl.length - results.length
  liColl.forEach(function(el) {
    if (index + 1 > liColl.length - diff) {
      // document.querySelector('ul').removeChild('li')
      // delete el
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Мне кажется, будет намного удобней не удалять лишние элементы, а полностью очищать и обновлять список

Comment: Да, спасибо 
Вариант

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, но все же пересоздавать список наверное проще.

```js
const result = [1, 2, 3];

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () =>
{
  const list = document.querySelectorAll('li');
  const listCount = list.length;
  const resultCount = result.length;

  if (listCount - resultCount < 1)
  {
    return;
  }
  
  for(let i = listCount; i > resultCount; i--)
  {
    list[i - 1].remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<button>Button</button>

<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```